# Is it possible to require a .php file via command line parameter before running a php script?

Tags: php, linux, bash, command-line-interface

### Situation

I'm running linux with a bash 4 compatible shell.

I have two files:

A.class.php:

```
<?php

class A{

    public static function foo(){
        echo "foo\n";
    }
}
```

A.php:

```
<?php

A:foo();
```

### Question

Is it possible to require A.class.php before running A.php from the command line without editing the files?

Something like:

```
php --require "A.class.php" A.php
```

### Things I tried

I tried to concatenate `<?php require 'A.class.php' ?>` with the contents of the file A.php and then pipe it to php like:

```
echo "<?php require 'A.class.php'?>$(<A.php)" | php
```

which works quite well but is kind of hackish and a lot to write. Maybe there is some *easier* way to do this?

Comment: `php -B '<?php require "test.php"?>' <test_run.php`? Or possibly `php -B '<?php require "test.php"?>' -f - <test_run.php`?

Comment: @EtanReisner This does not work! `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in Command line begin code on line 1
`. Btw sorry I had to change the file names.

Comment: Another option to preinclude another script is `php -d "auto_prepend_file=before.php" main.php`

Comment: @mario this looks very promising! I will test it ASAP and tell you if it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: @mario this works great. Do you want to create an answer your self or is it ok if i accept the answer from VolkerK? #repMatters

Comment: Just tick Volkers answer. The tickmark is also for future users, and indicates what you think was most practical. (Added a separate answer. Albeit that's less generic.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `-d directive=value` to set the [auto_prepend_file](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) directive.

```
php -d auto_prepend_file=A.class.php -f A.php
```

Or instead of passing script file names you could pass php code that loads the scripts directly as a parameter:

```
php -r "require 'A.class.php'; require 'A.php';"
```

Comment: Note that auto_prepend_file isn't parsed when used with "-r", not a bug but as designed https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33430

Answer (score 1):

As another alternative, there is always the *Unix way*:

```
 cat first.php second.php | php -C
```

Which joins the scripts together before running it through PHP.

- Unlike the `auto_prepend_file=` this works also with more than two scripts in series. (And doesn't hinder a central preload script. Personally using that already for compatibility code.)
- However, it **depends on** proper `<?php ... ?>` script enclosures - open ***and*** close tags in each script (classic PHP coding style, not noob/PSR-x stinted).
- (One could use [`phptags -w -c *.php`](http://fossil.include-once.org/phptags/index) to fix existing PHP files for such purposes.)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is likely the -f switch.

```
php -f phpFileToParseAndRunFirst.php
```

You can always create a short PHP file to run first that does the requires for you:

```
<?php
require ('pathToRequiredPhpFile1.php');
require ('pathToRequiredPhpFile2.php');

// Or even use the include to bring a .php file into the currently running script file as if it were a part of the script.
```

[From the PHP website](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php)

Comment: Sorry but creating a new file does not answer my question. From the title: `via command line parameter`. Could you be more specific about the -f switch? As I understand I would pass A.class.php as parameter for `-f` but how do I pass the file I want to run?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better example. In the same directory where you have your A.class.php Create a simple php init file (init.php) with this code:

```
<?php
include "A.class.php";
$x = new A;
$x->foo();
```

Now from the command line run this:

php -f init.php

Output:

foo

Take a look at php's documentation for the include statement as well as require() and require_once() functions as these can all be used together to accomplish what I think you are trying to do.

Comment: Did not edit any files. Created a new file called init.php as the bootstrap file that php should execute to load required files. I also demonstrated the use of include and suggesting looking into require() and require_once(). One other suggestion is to use composer. There is a switch -R which may work for you (I haven't used it myself) where it looks like you can pipe in php script files to be executed. Best of luck... :)